# Video Preview in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, preview

I just want to know after uploading the video in Video view.After clicking on the Button,the user picks the video from sd card and then he uploades in the Video View.And everything is working fine but I want to show the preview before the user clicks on the View.Can anyone please help me to sort this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Please share what you have tried or what error you are getting..

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

is a good example regarding this I guess

and to create thumbnail here is the code

```
Bitmap bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filepath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                            yourimageview.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```